# <div> position:absolute; bottom: 0; not working as expected in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, scroll

My site, a course catalog tool for universities, has a center pane that contains a dynamically updated list of classes. In Firefox, Opera, and Chrome, the center pane has the intended scrolling behavior: when the class list exceeds the height, the center pane has a scroll bar.  IE, however, only shows this bar when the height is explicitly set.  Without using JavaScript to reset the center pane height on resize, how can I force Internet Explorer to show the scroll bar?

The center pane:

```
<div id="middlenav">
    <div id="middleheader"></div>
    <div id="courselist"></div>
</div>
```

and its CSS:

```
div#middlenav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    right: 350px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

div#courselist {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It looks like the center pane isn't obeying the `bottom: 0px;` statement, and is expanding to the full height of the contained `#courselist`.  I tried `body { height: 100% }` but that didn't fix it either.

Comment: could we see a link to the site?

Comment: I don't know, but could http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ be applicable? I know you don't need a footer, but maybe some of the rules might help.

Answer (score 8):

> "The `top` property overrides the `bottom` property..."
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/bottom

Change `top` to `auto` instead of `0px`:

```
div#middlenav
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    right: 350px;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

That should fix the bottom positioning. Remember, if `#middlenav` is positioned absolutely, it will be relative to whichever parent element has `position:absolute;` or `position:relative;`. If `#middlenav` has no parent elements that are positioned, it will be relative to `<body>`.

I'm not sure why you have `#courselist` absolutely positioned; since it is inside of `#middlenav` I would think you could leave it static or position it relatively. But regardless of what you do, I think you need a height set on `#courselist` or `#middlenav`. The default value of height is auto, so there won't be a scrollbar because the element will expand to fit its content.

I know this question was asked 3 years ago, but I'm posting this for other people who may have a problem with CSS positioning. Cheers!

Comment: the top overrides the bottom - i'm in total shock. if mdn says so. in practice, its not true on a lot of browsers, i think ? http://jsfiddle.net/gcJvp/

Comment: @commonpike `top` overrides `bottom` only if the height is specified.

Answer (score 3):

While it is perfectly acceptable to set opposite edges when using absolute positioning in CSS, limitations in Internet Explorer mean that the approach may not work there.

There is no way to avoid the bug in Internet Explorer 6. In Internet Explorer 7 and newer, triggering Standards Mode will resolve the issue.

Faking columns that extend to the bottom of an element is usually achieved using [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

Comment: It's not "nice" and it's slower, but in IE6 a workaround is to use an alternate stylesheet/style and set top, with an expression for height. For this case if you use jQuery, top: 0px;  height: expression($(window).height())

Answer (score 1):

position: absolute; bottom: 0px; sets the element right on the bottom of the element. But it has to know where the bottom of the element is. If you set the height to 100% or have it in another element positioned bottom: 0px; Then it doesn't know where the bottom is, unless one of those elements is inside (taking up the full height of) and element with a fixed size. You can't give the body a height of 100% because it would just sort of go on forever. Try specifying the height of the body or some containing element. :D

Comment: The location of the bottom of the element will be calculated in the normal way. In this case #middlenav should span the height of the window (unless there is another element with position: not-static; in the way).

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your doctype is set to [HTML strict](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), otherwise IE will behave quirky and get confused with among others positioning and overflows.

Add this to top of your page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if i fully understand but I think you want the center pane to scroll when it reaches past a certain height..this is how I would do it.

```
#middlenav { position:absolute; left:250px; top:0 }
#courselist { position: absolute;top: 55px; left:0; min-height:400px; _height:400px;
              overflow:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; width:500px; }
```

This sets your course list in all browsers to a minimum height of 400, once that is passed a scrollbar appears. min-height is not supported in IE7 and lower so i used the IE hack _height 400 so it acts as a min height. overflow-x:hidden is hiding the horizontal scroll just in case you only want vertical. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score -10):

Don't use top and bottom positioning in the same class and don't use right and left positioning in the same class, as they are contradictory values to each other.

Comment: No, they aren't. With position: absolute, which is being used here, `left` sets the position of the left edge from the left, `right` sets the position of the right edge from the right, and so on.

Comment: Yes they are. If you set position:absolute, bottom:0, top:0 the bottom proprety will be ignored and top will have more priority.

Comment: Actually you can set all 4 position properties and you will have nice element with full with and height :-)